# Rails, api call every second and get data

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, websocket, cron

I am trying to call api every second. What did is;

1. I get the data from a controller action and use returned data on the view.
2. I write a ajax call function to API for every second from font end.

The problem is, when lots of users visit my site, then every user is making a call because of javascript.

I would like to use cron job like whenever gem or something but I do not know if I can process the return data on the front end when I use cron job. I want it to work as real-time.

So basically, the API call should be made from backend and update the page accordingly instead of front end. Do I have to use socket ?

Comment: If data provided to clientside is not specific to particular user, on page load you can create websocket connection and once cron job is finished, push data to all subscribers. But better describe your task in particular to think of possible other solutions

Comment: Yes it is not specific per user. So better to use Rails5 with websocket and cron job to get data per second (like whenever gem). But I'm not sure if I can process the returned data from whenever gem

Comment: Setup whenever to run background process, or ruby script, which will push data to socket. That seems all you need to do.

Comment: Alright, thank you for showing the path!

Comment: Whenever, based on Cron have the lowest unit of time as 1 minute. Which means it will update the data only every 1 minute. Then why not poll every 1 minute as well?

Comment: Actually I need every second, that is why I used ajax to call every second

Comment: Feel free to check out my [live_record gem](https://github.com/jrpolidario/live_record) that handles real-time syncing of "Record" data. Depending on your use-case on what data you were requesting every second, you'd probably find some use of my gem [live_record](https://github.com/jrpolidario/live_record) :) Just define the models you need if you're gonna be syncing say... `User` model data. Then you can do something like `var user = new LiveRecord.Model.all.User({id: 13}); user.addCallback('after:update', function() { // do something here after this user has been changed/updated });`

Comment: Thank you for bringing a gem for this. But I would like to send a request to an API every second. Think this as an exchange.